# How to expand the table data on clicking on Show More button in Ant Design (React.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, antd-mobile

Are there any ways to expand the table data to show more rows. The official Ant design document was not very helpful for this requirement as they have the instance only for the row expansion. But I need to expand the whole table upon clicking on some sort of "Show More" like button. Really appreciate the help.

```
Table before expansion
```

[image: Table Before Expansion]

```
Table After clicking on the Show More Button
```

[image: Table After clicking on the Show More Button]

Comment: would be nice if you could set up a reproduction jsfiddle or something similar, or at least show your code for the table!

Answer (score 0):

1. First make hidden the part you want to show with clicking and use hooks for that, such as true and false.
2. You can add values to table and remove with toggle logic like vanilla js